# How to track android phone call after dial the call button and before ringing in Android application

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to track the phone call information after dialing the call button and before ringing.Means before going call to the person whom I want to call, I want to a notification in my application.

Comment: @Dr.nik Thanks for ur quick reply. saw this contentObserver. Please explain on it. How it works and tracks the phone call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` with an [`ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) intent filter. You can also read [this Android Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) regarding some details on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Friend, I saw this ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.I hope it will help for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Try to read the phone number from previous receivers.
    String phoneNumber = getResultData();

    if (phoneNumber == null) {
      // We could not find any previous data. Use the original phone number in this case.
      phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

  }
}
```

**You can retrieve this from a Broadcast in response to ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL:**